# Display an image scale space in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have 8 images and I want to show them in a scale-space format shown below. The original image height and width is 256. Then on right side of original image, at every level the size is reduced by 2. Like here, image height and width is 256. On the right side of original image, height and width is 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4 , 2.

I have all the images in their respective dimensions. I just want to know how do I arrange the images according the pattern shown below. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to build a scale-space and displaying the results to the user.  This isn't a problem to do.  Bear in mind that you will have to do this with `for` loops, as I don't see how you will be able to do this unless you copy and paste several lines of code.  Actually, I'm going to use a `while` loop, and I'll tell you why soon.

In any case, you need to declare an output image that has as many rows as the original image, but the columns will be `1.5` times the original image to accommodate for the images on the right.

First, write code that places the original image on the left side, and the version that is half the size on the right.  Once you do this, you write a `for` loop, use indexing to place the images in the right spots until you run out of scales, and you need to keep track of where the next image starts and next image ends.  Bear in mind that the origin of where to write the next images after the first subsampled one will start at the column location of the original image, and the row is right where the previous one ends.  As an example, let's use the `cameraman.tif` image that is exactly `256 x 256`, but I will write code so that it fits any image resolution you want.  When I subsample the image, I will use [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) in MATLAB to help with the resizing of the image, and I'll specify a sampling factor of `0.5` to denote the subsampling by 2.  The reason why I would use a `while` loop instead, is because we can keep looping and resizing **until** one of the dimensions of the resized image is `1`.  When this is the case, there are no more scales to process, and so we can exit.

As such:

```
%// Read in image and get dimensions
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
[rows,cols] = size(im);

%// Declare output image
out = zeros(rows, round(1.5*cols), 'uint8');
out(:,1:cols) = im; %// Place original image to the left

%// Find first subsampled image, then place in output image
im_resize = imresize(im, 0.5, 'bilinear');
[rows_resize, cols_resize] = size(im_resize);
out(1:rows_resize,cols+1:cols+cols_resize) = im_resize;

%// Keep track of the next row we need to write at
rows_counter = rows_resize + 1;

%// For the rest of the scales...
while (true)
    %// Resize the image
    im_resize = imresize(im_resize, 0.5, 'bilinear');
    %// Get the dimensions
    [rows_resize, cols_resize] = size(im_resize); 
    %// Write to the output
    out(rows_counter:rows_counter+rows_resize-1, cols+1:cols+cols_resize) = ...
        im_resize;

    %// Move row counter over for writing the next image
    rows_counter = rows_counter + rows_resize;

    %// If either dimension gives us 1, there are no more scales
    %// to process, so exit.
    if rows_resize == 1 || cols_resize == 1
        break;
    end
end

%// Show the image
figure;
imshow(out);
```

This is the image I get:

[image]

Comment: I am getting black image as output. Moreover, all the scaled images are present in L{} array. I have added your code with mine in above post. Could you please tell about it?

Comment: @nikhilk - Your code works.  But, the reason why you're getting it completely black is because your images are `double` and are normalized between `[0,1]`.  I assumed your images were `uint8`, and so the expected range is between `[0,255]`.  If you make the output `uint8`, and if your intensities are between `[0,1]`, then you won't see anything!  As such, change the `out` declaration to this instead: `out = zeros(rows, round(1.5*cols));`.